# Gas Car vs EV Falling Off Cliff

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

As you may have heard, in a recent, allegedly criminal incident, a man in California drove a Tesla off a cliff with his family in it. The vehicle fell over 200 feet to the slope below, landed upside up, rolled several times on its side. As tragic as it was, the family survived with no death. Some expert said they were lucky because Tesla's battery pack was spread on the bottom of the car, unlike in a conventional gas vehicle where the engine in the front would have caused the car to be front heavy. And it would have nosedived. I am trying to figure out if this expert's comment is valid.

To simplify the problem, let's suppose a car with a gas engine is held by a crane 200 feet above the ground in a horizontal position. When the car is dropped, would it land nose first?

To think about this, I further simplify and divide the car to half, front and back. Assuming the air resistance force being the same for the front and back, I now have the following:

```
a1 = F1/m1 = (g*m1 - r)/m1 = g - r/m1
a2 = F2/m2 = (g*m2 - r)/m2 = g - r/m2
a1 - a2 = r/m2 - r/m1 = r*(m1 - m2)/m1*m2
```

(Where, a = acceleration, m = mass, F = net force, r = force of air resistance on half the car, g = gravitational acceleration, 1 for front and 2 for back. a1 - a2 would be the difference in acceleration.)

Let's say a conventional car weighs 3500 lb. and the engine part is 500 lb. Let's suppose the rest of the mass is equally distributed front and back. We will have:

```
m1 = 2000
m2 = 1500
a1 - a2 = r*500/3000000 = r * 0.00017
```

Calculating the resistance force would be too complicated. But since this is just a car without a parachute, it should be small.

It looks like with the falling distance of 200 feet, the difference in acceleration wouldn't be enough to make the car nosedive, although the front wheels may touch the ground first. In other words, the EV does not have an advantage in this incidence due to its even weight distribution.

Is this a reasonable conclusion?

(p.s. I realized I probably shouldn't use the pound here. If it is converted to kilo, the resultant 0.00017 would double approximately).

Comment: This was closed by the time I finished my answer. I should learn. If an answer has votes to close, I should post a quick placeholder answer. Then I can edit it when I am done. In this case, you can show that the Tesla nosedives more than a conventional car. The center of mass is closer to the rear wheels. When only the rear wheels are on the ground, there is a torque that makes any car nosedive. But if the CM is near the rear wheels, the moment of inertia is smaller, and the angular acceleration is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the numbers, but on general consideration I expect the same: under the specific circumstances of that crash I expect that weight distribution will not make a significant difference.

More generally:
My understanding is that Tesla cars are ahead of the cars of other manufacturers when it comes to protecting the occupants in the case of collision.

In this case:
On the information available I don't think it can be assessed whether the general protection measures of the Tesla car made a difference.